# High precision arithmetric in Python and/or C/C++?

Tags: c++, python, c, math, precision

**Abstract: Which Python package or C-Library is the best option for very high precision arithmetic operations?**

I have some functions which convert fractional days (`0.0-0.99999..`) to a human-readible format (hours, minutes, seconds; but more importantly: milliseconds, microsecond, nanoseconds).

Conversion is done by these functions:
(note that I haven't implemented timezone correction yet)

```
d = lambda x: decimal.Decimal(str(x))
cdef object fractional2hms(double fractional, double timezone):
    cdef object total, hms, ms_mult
    cdef int i
    hms = [0,0,0,0,0,0]
    ms_mult = (d(3600000000000), d(60000000000), d(1000000000), d(1000000), d(1000), d(1))
    # hms = [0,0,0,0,0]

    total = d(fractional) * d(86400000000000)
    for i in range(len(ms_mult)):
        hms[i] = (total - (total % ms_mult[i])) / ms_mult[i]
        total = d(total % ms_mult[i])

    return ([int(x) for x in hms])
```

And to fractional:

```
def to_fractional(self):
        output = (self.hour / d(24.0)) + (self.minute / d(1440.0))
        output += (self.second / d(86400.0)) + (self.millisecond / d(86400000.0))
        output += self.microsecond / d(86400000000.0)
        output += self.nanosecond * (d(8.64) * d(10)**d(-9))
        return output
```

My results of a back-and-forth conversion are inaccurate, however:

```
jdatetime.DayTime.fromfractional(d(0.567784356873)).to_fractional()
Decimal('0.56779150214342592592592592592592592592592592592592592592592592592592592592592592592592592592592592592592592592592')
# Difference in-out: Decimal('0.000007145270')
```

When I change `d()` to return a regular Python float:

```
# Difference in-out: 7.1452704258900823e-06 (same)
```

My question is therefore: Which Python package or C-library is able to do this more accurately?

Comment: What language is this? `cdef object fractional2hms(...):` doesn't look like Python to me. But anyway: How come you're starting out with a double and only afterwards convert that to a Decimal? You should start out with Decimals and never leave that realm if precision is an issue.

Comment: @Tim: yes it's Cython www.cython.org

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is due to a bug in your code, not due to any accuracy issue.  The line

```
output += self.nanosecond * (d(8.64) * d(10)**d(-9))
```

should be something like

```
output += self.nanosecond / d(86400000000000)
```

Furthermore, it is a Bad Idea to use floating point literals in your code and convert them to `Decimal`.  This will first round the literal number to floating point accuracy.  The later conversion to `Decimal` can't restore the lost accuracy. Try

```
d = decimal.Decimal
```

and use only integer literals (just remove the `.0` part).

Comment: Thanks! of course that should have been 8.64*10**9. And indeed, using integers for that is a more wise solution.

Answer (score 2):

CTRL-F "Libraries" there: [Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic)

EDIT: Extracting from the link libraries for c++ and python only (and removing some, that don't have floating numbers, but only integers)

**python**

1) [mpmath](http://code.google.com/p/mpmath/)

---

**c++**

1) [apfloat](http://www.apfloat.org/)

2) [base one number class](http://www.boic.com/numintro.htm)

3) [bigfloat](http://bigfloat.codeplex.com/releases/view/37938)

4) [lidia](http://www.cdc.informatik.tu-darmstadt.de/TI/LiDIA/)

5) [mapm](http://www.tc.umn.edu/~ringx004/mapm-main.html)

6) [MIRACL](http://www.shamus.ie/)

7) [NTL](http://www.shoup.net/ntl/)

8) [ttmath](http://www.ttmath.org/ttmath)

Comment: @Izz add-Din Ruhulessin, the answer can be usefull, don't you think so? if nobody suggests some particular library or say which is better, then you either pick randomly or look for links more preciesly.

Comment: Hi Max, thanks for your answer. Re-reading my comment, I conclude that it is more hostile than I intended. My apologies if I in any way offended you. I placed it before your edit however; your edited answer narrows down the the search a bit.