# Best coding language for dealing with large numbers (50000+ digits)

Tags: math, programming-languages, calculator, largenumber

Can you recommend good languages to do math with large numbers in?

So far I've used Actionscript 2 and Objective-c and with Objective-c even using `NSDecimalNumbers` I was limited to 32 digits in my calculations... I would need at a minimum to be able to calculate with numbers fifty-thousand digits long.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773603/high-precision-arithmetric-in-python-and-or-c-c.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps [Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/tutorial/numbers.html) will appeal to you.

Answer (score 10):

Python has arbitrary-length integers and uses them transparently, so you don't need any special code or classes for this.

```
>>> len(str(math.factorial(123456)))
574965
```

Comment: Nice. What about arrays? Are their indices limited by int.MAX_VALUE?

Comment: If you look at `help(sys)`, you'll see that `sys.maxsize` is "the largest supported length of containers". On my system, that's equal to 2**63-1, but the actual upper bound will be much lower, a) because even on a 64 bit system, only up to 52 bits can be used to address memory, so 4 PB, and b) because containers in Python have a lot of overhead, so your lists are not comparable to, say, a C array.

Answer (score 4):

Try also [bc](http://www.gnu.org/software/bc/), which is probably already installed in your machine.

Answer (score 2):

Nowadays most languages have some kind of support for arbitrary length numbers, natively on the language or via some external library (i.e. gmp).

The only important difference<sup>*</sup> is the level of integration within the language. For instance, in C++, Python, Perl, SWI-Prolog, Haskell, C#, etc., big-ints can be manipulated as any other built-in numeric type using the standard math operators. On the other hand in languages not supporting operator overloading as C, Objective-C, Java, etc. you have to use the library functions explicitly.

Depending on the pervasiveness of big-int operations on your application it may pay off to switch to a more big-int friendly language or not.

**update**

[*] well, obviously, correctness and speed also matter. But, as most languages use GMP under the hood, there shouldn't be mayor differences in that regard. Maybe math-oriented (and expensive!) languages/applications as Mathematica or Maple providing their own big-int implementations can have some advantage here.

Answer (score 1):

Try java with its `BigInteger` Class or you can look at writing a small library in C. If the Math is fairly simple you can always use arrays.

Perhaps try Matlab (not sure)

Comment: Matlab, like many other choices, relies on libraries or other extensions for arbitrary-precision calculations, they're not built in.  The quality of such libraries varies.

Comment: MATLAB does have a big integer tool, VPI, my own. I've since written a new one, based on the Java library that is much faster.

Comment: Java can take several hours to create a single large BigInteger - this is a race that Java will never win.