# Why the digits after decimal are all zero?

Tags: c++, c, floating-point-precision

I want to perform some calculations and I want the result correct up to some decimal places, say 12.
So I wrote a sample:

```
#define PI 3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751
double d, k, h;
k = 999999/(2*PI);
h = 999999;
d = PI*k*k*h;
printf("%.12f\n", d);
```

But it gives the output:

```
79577232813771760.000000000000
```

I even used setprecision(), but same answer rather in exponential form.

```
cout<<setprecision(12)<<d<<endl;
```

prints

```
7.95772328138e+16
```

Used long double also, but in vain.

Now is there any way other than storing the integer part and the fractional part separately in long long int types?

If so, what can be done to get the answer precisely?

Comment: Assuming that your computer also has limited memory, you can not represent the result precisely, you can however use arbitrary precision math libraries to represent it up to a chosen precision

Comment: @AdriC.S.
I have never seen `cout.setprecision(12)` before. I just knew `cout<<seprecision(12)<<d<<endl;`

Comment: @EricLeschinski: An integer multiplied by a double results in a double.

Comment: may I suggest http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: You got 16 decimal digits out of your number; you can't expect more out of a `double`.  (Sometimes, you can get 17; after that, you get random values — or zeros.)  Read the 'What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic' paper — easily found on SO or the Internet.

Comment: A double can store about 16 decimal digits of precision and that appears to be roughly what you are getting? What are you expecting to get as your result?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler but a long double must be capable of storing more than 16 decimal digits I guess? Even that fails.

Comment: @Sunny: No, it need not.  On some systems, `long double` is the same as `double`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - the digits after 16 or 17 are **not** random. Most programmers don't know enough about how the value is converted to decimal to predict what they are (and the conversion isn't necessarily well documented). But "I can't predict it" is not the same as random.

Comment: OK - I should probably have use 'meaningless' or something similar instead of 'random'.  The net result is not all that different in practice.

Comment: @PeteBecker, not "random" but "nonsense" relative to the exact answer of the computation. I guess we get used to "random nonsense" as a phrase.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus - "nonsense" is much better. `<g>`

Comment: @AndrewLazarus - the reason I object to "random" is that it encourages beginners to throw up their hands whenever some floating-point calculation produces a different result than they expected, rather than dig into what's really going on.

Comment: @PeteBecker the word "random" always draws my attention rather than giving up/ignoring.

Comment: Incidentally, your C++ implementation appears to be using extended precision for at least part of the calculation. The exact mathematical answer is about 79577232813771762.3765. Calculated purely with IEEE-754 64-bit binary floating point would return 79577232813771744. So getting 79577232813771760 is better than you would expect from just `double`.

Comment: FYI: [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=pi*999999*%28999999%2F%282*pi%29%29*%28999999%2F%282*pi%29%29) gives a nice detail of the calculation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A double has only about 16 decimal digits of precision. Everything after the decimal point would be nonsense. (In fact, the last digit or two left of the point may not agree with an infinite-precision calculation.)

Long double is not standardized, AFAIK. It may be that on your system it is the same as double, or no more precise. That would slightly surprise me, but it doesn't violate anything.

Comment: So sir, what other options are left with me to obtain the exact result?

Comment: Just in the interest of being a purist from my old University Physics days, I would add that the "999999" values with no declaration of decimals after it, implies he shouldn't be looking for more than six figures of precision in his answer. But that's splitting hairs. The fact remains, he's asking for more precision than a double can offer him.

Comment: There are several libraries set up for extra-precision arithmetic. Another answer mentions Gnu Multiprecision (GMP) library[http://http://gmplib.org/]. You should realize few real-world engineering applications will have any meaning to a 17th decimal place. You might share with us what you are trying to do, if it isn’t an arbitrary exercise.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus I don't want to use an external library for that. I want my code to be standard.
This being a part of a problem in a contest, I cant use a library other than standard anyway.

Comment: @Sunny: Then you'll have to code your own number class that supports higher precision, because the standard does not support it.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley seems legit.

Comment: @Sunny, I encourage you to look at the GNU code (or, if you read Java, the BigDecimal class). A lot of thought has gone into making these multiprecision libraries _correct_, and the chances of tossing your own off as part of a much bigger project and having it be good are not that high.

Answer (score 4):

You need to read [Double-Precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format) concepts again; **more carefully**.

The `double` has increased precision by using 64 bits.
Stuff before the decimal is more important than that after it.
So, when you have a large integer part, it will truncate the lower precision -- this is being described to you in various answers here as `rounding off`.

---

**Update**:
To increase precision, you'll need to use some library or change your language.
Check this other question: [Best coding language for dealing with large numbers (50000+ digits)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14723583/70482)

#### Yet, I'll ask you to re-check your intent once more.

- Do you really need 12 decimal places for numbers that have really high values
  (over 10 digits in the integer part like in your example)?
- Maybe you won't really have large integer parts
  (in which case such code should work fine).
- But if you are tracking a value like `10000000000.123456789`,
  I am really interested in exactly which application you are working on (astronomy?).
- If the integer part of your values is some way under `10000`, you should be fine here.

---

**Update2**:
IF you must demonstrate the ability of a specific formula to work accurately within constrained error limits, the way to go is fixing the processing of your formula such that the least error is introduced.

Example,

- If you want to do say, `(x * y) / z`
- it would be prudent to try something like `max(x,y)/z * min(x,y)`
- rather than, the original form which may overflow after `(x * y)`, loosing precision if that did not fit in the 16 decimals of `double`

#### If you had just 2 digit precision,

```
.               2-digit       regular-precision
 `42 * 7        290           297
 (42 * 7)/2     290/2         294/2
 Result ==>     145           147

       But ==>  42/2 = 21
                21 * 7 = 147
```

**This is probably the intent of your contest.**

Comment: That explains the behavior of all zeroes, but I am still clueless on the other part of the question, how to still get the result?

Comment: As I commented somewhere, that this being a part of a problem from a contest, my answer A(correct output B) will be considered as correct if and only if |A − B| ≤ 10^-11 * B

Comment: That was a great hint. Let me try more and then I will inform you back . Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The double-precision binary format used by most computers can only hold about 16 digits, after that you'll get rounding. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

Answer (score 1):

Floating point values have a limit range of digits. Just because your "PI" value has six times as many digits as a `double` will support doesn't alter the way the hardware works.

A typical (IEEE754) `double` will produce approximately 15-16 decimal places. Whether that's 0.12345678901235, 1234567.8901235, 12345678901235 or 12345678901235000000000, or some other variation.

In other words, yes, if you calculate your calculation EXACTLY, you'll get lots of decimal places, because `pi` never ends. On a computer, you get about 15-16 digits, no matter what input values you use - all that changes is where in that sequence the decimal place sits. To get more, you need "big number support", such as the Gnu Multiprcession (GMP) library.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You're looking for [`std::fixed`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed).</strike>  That tells the ostream *not* to use exponential form.

```
cout << setprecision(12) << std::fixed << d << endl;
```

Comment: I tried, this does not work at all. same output as using printf.

Comment: @tacp Ah, you want 12 decimal places **past** the "ones position" - not 12 decimal places *total*.  See the other answers then.  They're good.